# When building an React application using electron-builder, the application gets installed, but upon launching, an error occurs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, electron, electron-builder

When building an application using electron-builder, the application gets installed, but upon launching, an error occurs. However, the application works correctly in the browser, loading all the styles and components properly.

The issue seems to be that when the application is launched in Electron, it uses a different path instead of the one used in the browser version.

Additionally, the application fails to load the icon even though it is properly configured. It seems that some styles are not being loaded during the electron-builder build process. The error message displayed is: "default Electron icon is used, reason=application icon is not set."

[screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJTCw.png)
[screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P53bw.png)

my electron file main.cjs:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1600,
    height: 1200,
  })

  win.loadFile(path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'dist/index.html'))
};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
})
```

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "electron/main.cjs",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "previev": "vite previev",
    "package": "electron-builder"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "2.0.4",
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "5.3.6",
    "@emotion/react": "11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/timeline": "6.1.7",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.11.16",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.129",
    "@mui/material": "5.13.0",
    "@mui/system": "5.12.3",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "6.4.0",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "3.1.9",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.9.5",
    "@untitled-ui/icons-react": "0.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "3.40.0",
    "aws-amplify": "5.2.1",
    "D": "^1.0.0",
    "date-fns": "2.30.0",
    "draft-js": "0.11.7",
    "firebase": "9.22.0",
    "formik": "2.2.9",
    "gray-matter": "4.0.3",
    "i18next": "22.4.15",
    "lodash.debounce": "4.0.8",
    "lodash.isequal": "4.5.0",
    "mapbox-gl": "2.14.1",
    "mui-one-time-password-input": "1.1.0",
    "nprogress": "0.2.0",
    "numeral": "2.0.6",
    "prop-types": "15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "1.4.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "13.1.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "1.15.0",
    "react-dropzone": "14.2.3",
    "react-helmet-async": "1.3.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "2.4.1",
    "react-i18next": "12.2.2",
    "react-map-gl": "7.0.23",
    "react-markdown": "8.0.7",
    "react-quill": "2.0.0",
    "react-redux": "8.0.5",
    "react-router": "6.11.1",
    "react-router-dom": "6.11.1",
    "react-slick": "0.29.0",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "15.5.0",
    "redux": "4.2.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "2.4.2",
    "simplebar-react": "3.2.4",
    "stylis": "4.2.0",
    "stylis-plugin-rtl": "2.1.1",
    "yup": "1.1.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "xxx",
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ]
    },
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*",
      "electron/main.cjs",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "nsis": {
      "uninstallDisplayName": "Uninstall this app",
      "oneClick": "false",
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": "true"
    },
    "directories": {
      "output": "releases",
      "buildResources": "dist"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash.debounce": "4.0.7",
    "@types/lodash.isequal": "4.5.6",
    "@types/lodash.throttle": "4.1.7",
    "@types/node": "20.1.4",
    "@types/nprogress": "0.2.0",
    "@types/numeral": "2.0.2",
    "@types/react": "18.2.6",
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "13.1.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "@types/react-draft-wysiwyg": "1.13.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.25",
    "@types/react-slick": "0.23.10",
    "@types/react-syntax-highlighter": "15.5.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.59.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.59.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "4.0.0",
    "electron": "^24.3.1",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
    "eslint": "8.40.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4",
    "vite": "4.3.5"
  }
}
```

I have attempted several troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue. Firstly, I checked the Electron application's configuration files and ensured that the necessary paths and settings were correctly set. I also verified that all the required dependencies and packages were installed. Additionally, I reviewed the electron-builder documentation and made sure I followed the recommended guidelines for packaging and building the application.

My expectation was that after building the application using electron-builder, it would run smoothly without any errors. I anticipated that all the styles, components, and the application icon would be loaded properly, mirroring the functionality of the browser version. However, despite these efforts, I encountered the error message regarding the application icon and some missing styles.

//edit
index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json" />
        <!--  Favicon  -->
        <link rel="icon" href="./assets/xxx-logo.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./assets/xxx-logo.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/xxx-logo.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./assets/xxx-logo.png" />
        <!--  Fonts  -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@300;400&display=swap" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:wght@600;700&display=swap" />
        <!--  Vendors  -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
        <title>xxx</title>
        <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index-43badc11.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/index-f4cfbf02.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        
      </body>
    </html>
```

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTmZI.png)

Comment: Can you also share the directory structure or (basic)index file?

Comment: @VaibhavGidde Of course, I have already added the index.html file.

Comment: have you tried by adding homepage in package.json and by loading file index.html directly e.g win.loadFile('index.html')?

Comment: @VaibhavGidde 
I haven't tried, could you please describe in detail how I should do it?

Comment: I mean in your createWindow method have you tried loading index.html instead of path and dist/index.html.. replace it with win.loadFile('index.html') and also specifiy "hompage": ./" in package.json

Comment: Also to resolve electron icon issue you have to provide icon path under win key in package.json (in your case you have used logo.png)
"icon": "build/favicon.ico"

Comment: @VaibhavGidde 
I have already fixed that, the icon is now being displayed properly. However, I still have an issue with Electron and the correct functioning of my application.

Comment: @VaibhavGidde In my "package.json" file, I encountered an error after adding the "homepage" key. The problem is that the "electron-builder" library does not directly support the "homepage" key in the "build" section. 
After changing the path to win.loadFile('index.html'), a blank white background appears and no values are being loaded.